# SAS-MEANS/SUMMARY Procedure output

Tags: sas

Since I need to standardizing (subtracting the mean and dividing by standard deviation) my dataset, I should mean and standard deviation of price and volume of each stock in each date. Particularly, my dataset includes different stock and date as shown in the following pic.

[image: data set]

Hence, I used the following code to output mean and standard deviation.

```
proc summary data=HAVE nway;
class _ric date;
var price volume;
output out=WANT(drop=_:) mean= std=/autoname;
run;
```

However, my output table only has date, mean, and standard deviation. I don't why the RIC isn't included in the output table. How could I solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataset doesn't have the variable `_RIC` because you told it to drop all variables whose name starts with `_`. Just be more specific in the variables you drop.

```
out=WANT(drop=_type_ _freq_)
```